# Convert a column matrix into a logic array

Tags: matlab, octave

I have an m x 1-size matrix  Y of integers ranging from 1 to 10. I want to create a logic array of size m x 10 with the logic Y(i) == 1:10. And I don't want to use a for-loop.

What I've done is define a function

```
f = @(y) (y == 1:10)'.
```

Which I then call with `arrayfun(f,y,'UniformOutput',false)` which gives me a cell with the correct output. I then convert the cell into a matrix with `cell2mat`.

This feels a bit contrived so my question is: Is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: The duplicate has what you want. Simply transpose the output when you're done.

Comment: Might be a duplicate but rather a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8045025/convert-vector-into-logical-matrix?rq=1). Also the solutions you gave are not as clean nor as [fast](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2008/08/04/comparing-repmat-and-bsxfun-performance/) as the one by Mohsen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is

```
bsxfun(@eq, y, 1:10)
```

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

If i get you right:

```
f=logical(Y)
```

http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/logical.html

Hope this helps

Comment: This will return true for all nonzero `y`. `y=11` or `y=pi` should return false, for instance.

Comment: I don't think this will do. You see I want an mx10 matrix from a mx1, i.e. I want to make every element of Y into a row vector. Using logical seems to perform a logic operation elementwise.

Comment: ah sorry I missread that!